# Difference Between Endpoint and Connector in Mule

Tags: mule

What is the difference between Endpoint And Connectors in Mule . For example , there is http endpoint and there is http connector . Are these terms used interchangeably ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Connectors:**

- provide abstract layer over data transport mechanisms
- Mule specific
- provide connections to external resources(Protocols, DB, 3rd party
  API)
- Are Operation-based or Endpoint-based.

**Endpoints:**

- Flow level elements
- Represents specific usage of a Connector
- When you drag a Connector from palette into canvas, an Endpoint is
  created
- Any Connector can function as an Endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Endpoints are a type of connector.  Connectors in Mule are either endpoint-based or operation-based. Endpoint-based connectors follow either a one-way or request-response exchange pattern and are often (but not always) named and based around a standard data communication protocol, such as FTP, JMS, and SMTP. Operation-based connectors follow an information exchange pattern based on the operation that you select and are often (but not always) named and based around one or more specific third-party APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't confused about this, its in mule document

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-fundamentals/v/3.7/mule-connectors

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/endpoint-configuration-reference